# C++ standard thread class?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have come across many ad hoc implementations of thread class in C++, but why is there no standard library thread class like the one in Java? The one that I generally use in C++ is http://www.linuxdocs.org/HOWTOs/C++Programming-HOWTO-24.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`std::thread` will be standardized in [C++0x](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#std-thread), and many compilers already support it.

It is perhaps more ambitious than your cited example as construction/destruction signifies initiation/joining of thread execution.

Here's [another article](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-1-starting-threads.html).

Comment: Excellent! Interesting name to the standard :)

Comment: The name of the standard will probably be C++11 when it is formally adopted.  I've been trying this out using g++ 4.4.

Answer (score 8):

Until C++0x arrives, I recommend using the [Boost Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/thread.html) class, which is about as close to a standard as we have for the kind of Thread class you're after.

Answer (score 2):

C++ was invented in 1979. I don't think the notion of threads was really widespread at that time. (While there were multi-user and multi-process OSes back then, they were all very peculiar in their own ways. For example, it took until 1995 for pthreads to be standardised.)

Answer (score 1):

For some more info on how to use std::thread see ...

std::threadhttp://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-1-starting-threads.html

You might want to do a test with your compiler to see if it supports it. If not until then use one of the other libs.